# Web Api Core dependency error

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to open this project on my visual studio 2015:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/992208/Angular-JS-Application-with-MVC-Web-API-ASPNET-and

When I open the project I get the following message:

> DNX SDK version '....1.0.0-beta4-11566' is required by your solution
>   but is not installed on this machine. Do you want to install it now?
>   If you select No, '...1.0.0-rc1-update1' will be used as the solution
>   DNX SDK Version for this session.

I choose Yes and it failed to install the DNX SDK version so it uses version 1.0.0-rc1-update1.

Then, I get this error:

> The dependency Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core 5.2.3 in project ... does
>   not support framework DNXCore, Version=v5.0.

I am running the most recent version of Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10. I have tried updating everything, everything is up to date. I don't know why I keep getting this annoying error. I tried using different versions of the WebApi.Core from the most recent to the first version.

It's also important to mention that I am new to the whole ASP.NET 5 concept, I'm used to work with MVC 5 and under.

Comment: Same problem here. Did you solve it?

Comment: @drizin I am afraid i have not solved the problem. But i did see a neat pluralsight course on mvc 6 and now no longer require this example.